# Restricting Permissions In WordPress Multisite Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, permissions, multisite

I created a WordPress Network and for the most part I have been able to gate access to the backend perfectly using a plugin called "User Role Editor Pro" to modify access based on user role.

The problem is I cannot figure out what the permissions should be for the following navigation items: "

- Dashboard > My Sites
- Dashboard > Add New Site

You can see what I mean in the following screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/Y91cGtJhQd

I've scoured the WP Documentation but cannot seem to find it. I also tried it in PHP with the following code:

```
 function remove_menus(){
    remove_menu_page( 'my-sites.php' );    // Dashboard
    remove_menu_page( 'index.php?page=wu-new-site' );    // Dashboard
 }
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

But that has two problems... Frist it doesn't work, and two even if I did remove it from the nav, it would remove the permission so anyone familiar with WP could just paste a URL and access it. This is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

You could just hide it with the remove_menu_page, and make a separate action, in the admin_init, that checks if the current screen is my_sites.php or index.php?page=wu-new-site and redirect to the dashboard, creative approach.

This doesn't solve the issue with xml-rpc most likely, so you'll most likely have to filter with that one too.

my-sites.php seems to be accessible to anyone that has "read" access, I suppose the reasoning is to allow users to navigate trough any sites they are registered trough the network easily.

Did you find an elegant solution for this ? I'm thinking the redirects & hiding from interface might be the only solution.